# InDesign: Prevent table headers from repeating

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables

I have a long table that breaks across multiple pages. It has a header which I only want to appear once at the beginning of the table. But InDesign is adding the header at the top of every page when the table breaks onto the next page. How can I prevent the header from appearing on every page?

I checked out Table Options but, as show below, there is no option to say, "Never repeat the header".

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the **Header Rows** to `0`.

Then manually adjust the first row of the table to appear like the header you want.

In short.. *do not* use the "header row" function for the table. It's *entire function* is to repeat rows as headers.

Comment: I had actually been doing this but just added a real header to all my tables to take advantage of styles. It's a convenience that now my tables will automatically format their header when I apply the table style. So you are saying there is no way to stop the header rows from repeating?

Comment: You can use Cell Styles to apply common styles. If you do not want header rows to repeat... the "header row" needs to be set at 0.

Answer (score 1):

It's a strange thing that this is not an option that can be set on the table style. I'm in the same situation as @peacetype. We've got a document that is almost done, and now the customer doesn't want the headers to be repeated at all.
Setting the header rows to 0 (suggested above) actually *deletes* those rows, so that is not an option for an existing table, only when building tables from scratch.

To change header rows into body rows and keep the cell data of the rows, you need to select the row, right-click and select "Convert to Body Rows".

Comment: **Headers rows** are customarily column titles, NOT data.  if you have header rows repeating and they contain data, you've used header rows incorrectly from the start. The *entire point* of designating header rows is so you can set their repeats, NOT so you can style them. Styling header rows is secondary. If you merely want styles, use Styles.

Comment: @Scott I believe Andreas is using ‘data’ in a broader sense here, equivalent to ‘content’; headers in table cells (even cells in header rows) are also data, just as any other content in a document is data. Regardless of what you have in your headers, you presumably don’t want it to disappear entirely when converting header rows to body rows.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I don't know... I imagine you probably *would* want column *titles* to disappear if you are removing header rows. Actually Header rows repeat the same style and data for each header. If the data is different in different text frames or on different pages, you should *not* be using the Header Rows function.

Comment: @Scott: The thread starter and I describe situations where a "no repeat" setting would be suitable, and none of us wants data to be deleted. I've imported xml (head AND cell data), creating 100s of tables in my doc w headers repeated for each column as they were in a similar document years ago (no mistake). Now that our customer decides the headers are not to be repeated, InDesign lacks the ability to change this in a simple way (I'll resort to scripting Convert+explicit Cell styles). Using Table styles, header rows can not be styled differently from body rows, unless they ARE headers.